# Removing properties of an object in List<>

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop

I'm listening to "push" notifications coming into my server. I've set up `SubscriptionModel` with all possible properties, and I can correctly iterate through the JSON body coming through, parse each Subscription, and modify the output before returning the list I created.  However, I'd like to know how I might go about removing properties of `SubscriptionModel` when I don't need to return them at all; or removing them if they're null before responding back with `List<SubscriptionModel> subscriptions`.

```
namespace TextMessagingListener.Controllers
{
    public class SubscriptionModel
    {
        public long push_id { get; set; }
        public string request_id { get; set; }
        public string subscription_id { get; set; }
        public string message { get; set; }
        public string status_code { get; set; }
        public string error_message { get; set; }
    }

    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class SubscriptionController : Controller 
    {
        // PUT api/subscription
        [HttpPut]
        public List<SubscriptionModel> Put([FromBody] List<SubscriptionModel> model)
        {
            // Receive a report of whether your subscription(s) was successfully added or not.
            List<SubscriptionModel> subscriptions = new List<SubscriptionModel>();

            foreach (SubscriptionModel m in model)
            {
                m.message = "Push notification successfully received.";
                subscriptions.Add(m);
            }

            return subscriptions;
        }
    }
}
```

The only solution I can think of is to create another object which will just be for returning information; and applying each `subscriptions` item I want to send on to that.

Comment: Sidenote: u should write your properties `Pascal` case https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2dbyw72(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: @Sybren good to know moving forward.

Comment: @Sybren Sidenote: "you" is spelled with more letters than one ;).

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan >>>you<<<  got me there, can't edit it anymore though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. You'd need another class. A "light" version that contains just the properties. Or you could do an anonymous type, but that is difficult to work with. I agree with the other guy on your naming conventions though :).

Comment: The more I thought about it, the more I thought I needed just another class/object (*which term should I use?*). The Anonymous Type sounds interesting but is probably out of my grasp at this moment.

Comment: @TheGuitarShawn, nothing wrong with SubscriptionLiteModel or something like that. If you are publicly exposing it as an API or something like that, I might pick a different name, but for internal only, something like that is fine.